# How display (hierarchical) years and months of my articles creating (PHP, Yii2)?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have **articles** table in my **DB**:

```
id(int), title(varchar), text(text), created_date(date)
```

I need display all months and years of articles creating with count of articles like this:

```
2018
Jan (5)
Mar (7)
Jul (5)
Dec (1)

2017
Feb (12)
Sep (3)

2016 
Aug (13)
Sep (6)
Nov (2)
```

How can I do this with Yii2?

Comment: You are talking about how to do it in Yii2, but you havent elaborated if you have the raw SQL prepared or not otherwise it looks more like a homework, so what have you done so far at your end? because the result set you are looking for , if you want **exactly same** result set from the database tables , this wont be possible from a simple query or groupBy clause.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I dont now how to do this in yii but the basic query to access to this data   ,It would be something like this.

First execte this SQL query

```
SELECT YEAR(created_date),MONTH(created_date), COUNT(id) TotalCount
FROM articles
GROUP BY YEAR(created_date), MONTH(created_date);
```

This will return you a result  what you need , count all articles . by month and year.

Then what do yo need do now is implements this query into you project Yii2 and parse and split  how you need